# Windows WxPython open excel file that's already open

Tags: python, excel, windows, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm trying to read data from an excel file in Windows, but I'd rather not have to close the excel file to do this.
However, when I try to select an excel file that I have open, I get the warning

> This file is in use. Enter a new name or close the file that's in use by another program.

and when I try to open it anyway with pylightxl, I get the error

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'example.xlsx'

Obviously if I close the open file, it works fine. But why should I? I've saved the excel file (which should write the changes to disk) and I want only to read the data with Python.

Here's my test code:

```
import wx
import wx.xrc
import pylightxl as xl

def print_sheet_names(file):
    db = xl.readxl(file)
    for name in db.ws_names:
        print(name)
    

class MyFrame1 ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 261,202 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHints( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.m_filePicker1 = wx.FilePickerCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, u"Select a file", u"*.xlsx", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.FLP_OPEN )
        bSizer1.Add( self.m_filePicker1, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( bSizer1 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        # Connect Events
        self.m_filePicker1.Bind( wx.EVT_FILEPICKER_CHANGED, self.open_file )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass


    def open_file( self, event ):
        file = self.m_filePicker1.GetPath()
        print_sheet_names(file)


#print_sheet_names("example.xlsx")
app = wx.App(False)
frame = MyFrame1(None)
frame.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: did you try to contact the author of the library?  Can you open it without wx involvement?

Comment: I am not really sure, but I think its a standard behavior on winblows. In Linux, there is no such problems with open files. In winblows, it was done by (a very) design.

Comment: Yes, there's no issue on Linux, and even no issue on windows if the containing folder is shared with a Linux VM. @Igor The file fails to open if I hard-code the path too, as seen with the permission error 13.

Comment: @user1924347, did you try to contact the author of the library? It is also possible the Excel itself opens the file in the `exclusive mode` and you may not have any other choice...